# MySQL 'set names latin1' seems to cause data to be stored as utf8

Tags: mysql, encoding

I have a table defined as follows:

```
mysql> show create table temptest;
+------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Table      | Create Table                                                                                                  |
+------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| temptest | CREATE TABLE `temptest` (
  `mystring` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |
+------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

When I use mysql console (through mysql temptest) and insert a character through

```
insert into temptest values ("é");
```

I can see it is getting saved as "latin1" encoding

```
mysql> select hex(mystring) from temptest;
+---------------+
| hex(mystring) |
+---------------+
| E9            |
+---------------+
```

But if I issue a "set names latin1" and perform the same operation, I see it storing the same character in utf8 encoding.

```
mysql> set names latin1;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> insert into temptest values ("é");
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> select hex(mystring) from temptest;
+---------------+
| hex(mystring) |
+---------------+
| E9            |
| C3A9          |
+---------------+
```

As far as I understand, "set names" shouldn't affect how mysql stores the data (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/set-names.html). What am I missing here? Any insight into this would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: "What am I missing here?" é in latin1 or utf8 encoding is the same..

Comment: I don't think é in latin1 and utf8 are encoded to the same byte.

Comment: they are the latin1 chars in utf8 are backwards compatible

Comment: I'm not saying utf8 is not backwards compatible to latin1 for é. What I am saying is the byte encoding is not the same for é in latin1 vs utf8. And you said é is the same encoding in utf8 and latin1, which is not true. And I don't see how this answers my question.

Comment: The small letter é is both in ANSI and in ISO 8859-15 0xE9 (233), and in Unicode accordingly U + 00E9 (233), and is thus stored in UTF-8 as 0xC3 0xA9 (195 169)... So what you get is correct..

Comment: Maybe my question wasn't clear. I am asking why does issuing "set names latin1" cause the character é to be encoded as utf8 whereas before issuing the set names command, it was being encoded as latin1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `SET NAMES latin1` declares that the encoding in your *client* is latin1.
2. But (apparently) it is actually utf8.
3. So, when you type `é`, the *client* generates the 2 bytes `C3 A9`.
4. Then those are sent *as if they were latin1* to the server (mysqld).
5. The Server says "Oh, I am getting some latin1 bytes, and I will be putting them into a latin1 column, so I don't need to transform them.
6. In go *two* latin1 characters `Ã©` (hex C3A9).  This is called Mojibake.
7. If you do `SET NAMES utf8` and `SELECT` the text, you will "see" `Ã©` and it will be 4 bytes (hex `C383C2A9`)!

Bottom line:  Your *client* encoding was really utf8, so you should have said `SET NAMES utf8` (or utf8mb4).  Confused?  Welcome to the club.